# How do I add taxonomy to my custom entity?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities, 8

I am working with a custom entity and I would like to be able to add taxonomy to the entity.  The drupal 8 entity documentation is lacking.

I have tried reading Node.php and term.php entitiy files but I don't understand how any sort of taxonomy is linked to any other entity though this.

Do I need to change something in my entity definition to allow taxonomy to be added? Or is there a way to access the taxonomy entity?

Edit:  I am working on the same pattern to add this to the install file of my module

```
'category' => array(
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'not null' => TRUE,
                'default' => '',
                'description' => 'The section front  to appear on',
            ),
```

this is the exception that I get trying to install the module

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error [error]
or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'The section
front  to appear on',
```

Comment: Taxonomy terms are entities too, so an entity reference field would probably be the best choice

Comment: For the edit: `varchar` columns require a `length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom entities, I would suggest to work with @ContentEntityType and baseFieldDefinitions() method, instead of creating the table on .install file.

You can see more details on why take this path in [When to use BaseFieldDefinition instead of hook_schema](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/170062/when-to-use-basefielddefinition-instead-of-hook-schema) an on this implementation.

A taxonomy field is now on D8 only an entity reference field, and you can have an example on how to use it at the field "voted_entity_id" at https://github.com/pedrorocha-net/votingapi/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Entity/Vote.php

Comment: Awesome!  This works,  now I just need to take it one step further and limit the vocabulary it can be.  Is that possible?

Comment: I think it is. You probably can add these settings when calling BaseFieldDefinition::create.
Take a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!src!Entity!Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8 to have as reference.

Answer (score 2):

As Clive said, you use an entity reference field for that, just like articles have a tags reference field to terms.

If you want to define it in code, it's really the same as the node.uid field, which is an entity reference to a user. Or the user.roles field, which is a multivalue reference to user roles. Entities reference others using an entity reference field, it's always the same pattern.

Comment: i am working on the same pattern to add this to the install file of my module